# Mongodb only insert if value is unique, else update - in node.js

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I've started developing an app recently and have finally got my node.js server communicating with my mongodb database.

I want to insert a bunch a JSON objects that look something like this:

```
   {
    'Username': 'Bob',
    'longitude': '58.3',
    'latitude': '0.3'
   }
```

If this Object is inserted into myCollection, and then I try to insert an object again with the Username Bob, but with different coordinates, I want the latest 'Username': 'Bob' object to replace the earlier one. There can only be one object in myCollection with the 'Username': 'Bob' basically.

If this was a relational database I would make Bob a primary key or something, but I was wondering what the best way to do this with mongoDb would be. Should I use the update+upsert method? I tried that and it didn't seem to work!

Apologies if this seems like a silly question, but I am still new to all of this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, a simple [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) query with the `upsert` option should satisfy your use case:

```
db.collection.update(
   {username:"Bob"},
   {$set:{'longitude': '58.3', 'latitude': '0.3'}},
   { upsert: true}
)
```

When you run the above query the first time (i.e., Bob doesn't exist in the collection), a new document is created.  But when you run it the second time with new values for lat/long, the existing document is updated with the new lat/long values.

You can also create a [`unique index`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the `username` field to prevent multiple records for 'Bob' from being created even accidentally:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "username": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

**EDIT:**

`db.collection.ensureIndex()` is now deprecated and is an alias for `db.collection.createIndex()`.  So, use [`db.collection.createIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) for creating indexes

Comment: Thanks! What if in the $set field I included the 'Username:Bob' field as well as the longitude and latitude? Also, does using ensure index of update have any benefits? Thanks again!

Comment: `$set` can include `'username':'Bob'`. Except for the `_id` field, we can modify any other field.  `_id` field is immutable.  Yes, creating an index (even a non-unique one) will help in this case because we are querying the collection by `username`.  If no index were present, it would be a full collection scan. Creating an index helps find the document quicker.  You can specify the `unique` option if that's your requirement.

Comment: As an update to this, `db.collection.ensureIndex()` is now deprecated, and is an alias for `db.collection.createIndex()`.

Comment: If I have more than these fields, i.e., fields not unique, not included in query, neither want to change, which I want to insert if the query returns null, but want to keep the same when updating, where can I include them? In `$set`?